# "Printer not ready" in Outlook (Office)

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, printing, printer

I have a customer with a few clients. Most of them have the following problem:
If you try to print from Outlook (and for some of them Word too) you get an error "Printer not Ready". It is with (sometimes only some of) the HP printers and also the "Microsoft Print to PDF". With CutePDF it works.

In at least one of the cases the problem came after a Windows Update.

Software combinations with the Problem:

- Windows 10 - Office 2010
- Windows 10 - Office 2013
- Windows 10 - Office 2016
- Windows 8.1 - Office 2013

What I've tried so far:

- Delete printer and reinstall it
- Change Printer Port (WSD, IP)
- Remove Driver from system and reinstall
- Reinstall Office

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you print from other applications when this issue happens, such as IE? You may first try Using HP Diagnostic Tools (download from here: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02073861) to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I can print from other programs, and HP Diagnostics won't help, because it is also the Microsoft Print to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: close Outlook and rename the `OutlPrnt` to `OutlPrnt.old` in the folder `%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook`, and then see whether this issue continues. The `OutlPrnt` file is used to keep all Outlook printing style settings. When this file get corrupted, you may run into several Outlook printing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user's Temp variables and make sure that Authenticated Users have full control of those folders.

On my images I move all of the Temp information to C:\Temp to make deleting temp files easier.  Once I gave Authenticated Users full control of the folder they were able to use the Microsoft Print to PDF printer.